# EntityFramework - Strategies to load childs objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository

I got the 2 following entity : User and Post

Simple version of user :

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

Posts aren't load by default.

In certain condition, I need to load the Posts (for example, I want to count the number of posts for that user). For now, I've add a method call LoadPosts(User user) in UserRepository:

```
_context.LoadProperty(user, "Posts");
```

- Is there a more logically place to put that method ?
- Should I put it in PostRepository ? Something like CountPosts(int userId) ?
- Should I offer an overload on my LoadMethod. Example : `Load(bool loadPosts)`

Is there a way that if I write myUser.Posts.Count() Posts is loaded automatically instead of being null ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scenario you are describing is called Lazy loading and it is supported by EF4. Judging by your code, you have POCO objects, and since you've declared your list as `virtual`, EF can create proxies in order to provide lazy loading features. There is a setting you can use to enable Lazy loading: `context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`. In this case, whenever you access the `Posts` property of an already loaded `User`, the data will get loaded from the DB.

More info here, in the "Deferred/Lazy Loading" section:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx

> The reason why this works is because
>   when I marked my collection property
>   as virtual, this allowed the Entity
>   Framework to provide a proxy instance
>   for my POCO type at runtime, and it is
>   this proxy that does automatic
>   deferred loading. The proxy instance
>   is based on a type that derives from
>   my own POCO entity class - so all
>   functionality you have provided is
>   preserved. From a developer point of
>   view, this allows you to write
>   persistence ignorant code even when
>   deferred loading might be a
>   requirement.

And briefly on your mini-question list:

- *Is there a more logically place to put that method ?* - If you decide to implement
  a method to load `Posts` for a given
  user yourself, it logically belongs to the
  `UserRepository`.
- *Should I put it in PostRepository ? Something like CountPosts(int userId)
  ?* - It might belong to the
  `PostsRepository` in case you load
  posts unrelated to a certain user
  (e.g. a global keyword search among
  all posts).
- *Should I offer an overload on my LoadMethod. Example : Load(bool
  loadPosts)* - Yes, you can do that.
  With EF, however, you just have to
  turn off Lazy loading. The Posts will
  get loaded together with the User.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom data provider, in that case I would suggest you to load the data in `CreateDataSource` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in Repository, by overloading or adding new method. [For More](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/designing-repositories-ndash-now-i-don-rsquo-t-feel-so-bad/)

If you are calling `_context.Load()` outside the repository than it may be [incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010183).

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a more logically place to put that method ?

IMO, yes. I wouldn't have a specific method like that unless you require a list of posts a lot of time. I would *Eager Load* the Posts *on demand*. (More on this, below)

> > Should I put it in PostRepository ?

Sorta. `LoadPosts(User user)` is a PostRepository specific login, IMO. BUT - it's a *very* specific method .. which means that sooner-or-later you're PostRepository will get very busy with lots of specific methods. We usually have a generic repository which allows *Expressions* to come in. That way, you don't need to create lots of specific methods. You can have one method that excepts *expressions* and retrieves your various requests.

for example.

```
IQueryable<Post> Find(Expression<Func<Post, bool>> predicate, 
                      string[] includeAssociations);
```

Then you can use it to eager load what you need.

eg. Get all posts for a particular user.

```
var posts = _postRepostitory
    .Find(x => x.UserId = userId, new [] { "User" } )
    .ToList();
```

or the flip side, For a user, get me all their posts...

```
var user = _userRepository
    .Find(x => x.UserId = userId, new [] { "Posts" } )
    .ToList();
```

If you need some help with the code inside the `Find` method, just ask .. but it's pretty trivial.

The idea is this (in order, which is cruical)

- the expression is just applied to the `Post` entity inside the hidden context inside the `postRespository` instance.
- Finally, you `Include` for each association that is required, last.

Nothing is hardcoded. It's all defined by the coder when they call the Find method :) *One method to rule them all.*

NOTE: Of course, i actually have 4 - one with no arguments .. all the way down to the one i've shown, with 4 args.

> > Something like CountPosts(int userId) ?

(Untested, pseduo code .. thinking off the top of my head)

```
var count = _postRepostiory
    .Find(x => x.UserId = userId, new [] { "Posts" })
    .Select(x => x.Posts).Count;
```

> > Should I offer an overload on my LoadMethod. Example : Load(bool loadPosts)

Nope. not needed now.

> > Is there a way that if I write myUser.Posts.Count() Posts is loaded automatically instead of being null ?

Yep, if you follow my suggestions above.

```
var user = _userRepository
    .Find(x => x.UserId = userId, new [] { "Posts" })
    .SingleOrDefault();

var postCount = user == null || user.Posts == null ? 0 : user.Posts.Count;
```

Go nuts and program away, padawan!!